# How to Prevent my LIKE button from Spamming on Client as well as Server Side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a 'LIKE' Button under each of the post on the webpage. When User Clicks on the 'LIKE' button it sends a GET request through AJAX to a like.php page that insert a row to mysql database table. after being clicked on the LIKE Button by a user the LIKE button disappears.

I want to ensure that there should be 3 seconds delay between the Clicks on 'LIKE' button by a user. I mean If a user click on the 'LIKE' button on a post and immediately he clicks on the LIKE button on the second post, and if this period is less than 3 seconds the LIKE button process should be denied.

Now, The Problem is That Where Should I Put this check, on Client Side or on Server Side. if One Server Side, A solution comes to my mind.

I thought to put this code to like.php page

```
if(isset($_SESSION["last_like_time"]))
{
    $last_like_time = $_SESSION["last_like_time"];
    $time_diff = time()-$last_like_time;
    if($time_diff<3)
    {
        die("ERROR: You must wait at least " . (3 - $time_diff) . " seconds to Like another Post");
    }
    $_SESSION["last_like_time"] = time();
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["last_like_time"] = time();
}
```

My Question is, Is this an efficient Way to Check the time difference on SERVER Side? If not Which is the best way?

My Second Question, How can I perform this action on Client Side without going to SERVER side?

Comment: You should not issue a `GET` in order to save data, use a `POST`.

Comment: @moonwave99 Actually, this Like Button is an `<a>` link. Can I send the data using POST request when some user click on `<a>` link??

Comment: You can't. But `<a>`-tags are meant for linking to a URL, not for sending data. Send it async via javascript, that's the common approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a security like this in the client. Because the client can change. If a user really want to spam you, he'll probably not use an browser.

In server side with php, `time()` is fine to check the last "like" action of the current user.

If you really want to put this security on the Client Side, you must use some javascript.

Comment: Am I using the Correct Method??

Comment: There's always a better method. But in a production environment, you sometimes can't do anything you want. You can check the time since the last request in your php code, it's fine. But you can also use Apache to deny too many request from the same IP on the same URL.